# cups with Ubuntu 14.04 very slow

Tags: printing, connection

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop. 
I have cups installed to connect to the printer server at my work place. On both systems I see all the printers but on Ubuntu 14.04 lpstat -p takes almost one minute and the same is true 
when I try to print from libreoffice or okular, amazingly the response from Gimp is extremely fast.
The response on my laptop is very fast.

I really don't know what to do. Can you help?